# Using a Django Custom Manager

Tags: django, django-models

Can anyone help me create a custom manager that does the following....

This is just a learning exercise for me, it's not a real application so I'm after as much explanation as possible.

**1) takes 2 objects, its self (Person) and Profile**

**2) divides person.age with profile.dog_years**

**3) adds this to model**

My guess is that first I create a custom manager in my models.py

```
class PersonManager(models.Manager):
    def make_score(self,profile):
```

Within the custom manager I then do the math self.age / profile.dog_years.

Then some how return it?

Add it to the model i.e. dogAge = PersonManager()

**Outcome:**

**Then what I'm hoping to happen is that when I get  all persons in my view
return Profile.objects.filter() (somehow pass profile here?) it has a new field called dogAge with the dog ages for all persons listed.**

Comment: Do you want to modify a list of Person or only one ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't something that you'd do in a Manager. This is a job for a normal Model method.

Manager methods are for things that modify the query in some way. That's not what you want to do: you want to annotate a property to each object in the queryset. Since that doesn't require any further database calculations, a model method is the appropriate place.